# Let $ \tau(\omega) =\inf \{ t \in (0, \infty): B_t(\omega) = 10\}$. Does it follow $P( \tau = s) = 0?$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Consider the first time the Brownian motion reaches $10$, i.e.
$$\tau(\omega) =\inf \{ t \in (0, \infty): B_t(\omega) = 10\}$$
Clearly, $P(B_t = 10) =0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R}^+$since the Brownian motion is normally distributed. But does it follow that
$$P( \tau = s) =0, \forall s \in \mathbb{R}^+$$
and does considering the interval $[0, \infty)$ make a difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $P(\tau = s) \leq P(B_s=10)=0$ since the event $\{\tau=s\}$ is contained in the event $\{B_s=10\}$, and since $B_s$ has a continuous distribution.

Note that this only shows that the law of $\tau$ is atomless, which doesn't necessarily imply that a density exists with respect to Lebesgue measure (think Cantor-type or local-time measures). If you want an explicit density for $\tau$ see theorem 2.32 on page 56 of [this book](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~peres/bmbook.pdf).

Comment: The way I see it, $\{ \tau = s \} \subset \{ B_s = 10\}$ follows from the fact that the paths of Brownian motion are a.s. continuous, doesn't it? To be more precise, the inclusion holds except for a null set.

Comment: One could say this shows it's continuous in the sense of having a continuous c.d.f. but it's more work to show it's continuous in the sense of having a density. The terminological confusion here is unfortunate.

Comment: @Holden yes, that is correct. Michael Hardy: very true.